# How to get position imageView in ListView Android

Tags: java, android, listview, listener

I have a list with pictures for each item, when I click on an image I need the position of the list.

how can I get this?

I tried to do `View.getTag().ToString()` but by mistake.

Here's the code:

```
ImageView im = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDSD);

im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(contextCustom,
                    "ImageView clicked for the row = " + v.getTag(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Error", "errore vista " + e);
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Your `getView()` method of CustomAdapter has already `int position` parameter. Make it `final` and use it in ImageView's `onClick()`. :)

Comment: Did you get my point?

Answer (score 1):

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
        {
            postion on your image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not applicable. OP needs in ImageView's Click which is individual View of List Row. Not complete ListRow's Click.

Comment: i donat understand so what u need

Comment: we can use onitemclick listner on listview to get pistion and image view we can not app oniltemclick becouse that contant single item

Answer (score 1):

On each getView, set the ImageView's tag to be equal to the list item's position.

Then in your listener you can get the tag, and determine which list item this image belongs to.

```
ImageView im = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDSD);
im.setTag(position);
```

Also note that you shouldn't create a new listener every time getView is called, instead do it only when `convertView` is null. However the tag should always be set regardless of convertView's value.

**Edit:**

Here's a full example of neat getView method (using a holder pattern to avoid `findViewById`):

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // (Re)Use the convertView
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDSD);
        holder.imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(contextCustom, "Pos: " + v.getTag(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.imgView.setTag(position);

    // Do something else with your image here

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: `getTag()` and `setTag()` only required if ImageView's `onClick()` is out of adapter's `getView()` method. Or you don't want to make `int position` parameter as `final`. Else you can directly use int position parameter in ImageView's `onClikc()` by declaring it as `final`.

Comment: @user370305 Creating a new listener for every call to getView is pretty stupid IMO.

Comment: Yes, But its Choice of OP. And by above code we can't say anything for creating new listener, for that we need complete code.